# How do I create a GridLayout of a specific size and location with kivy

Tags: python, kivy

I am experienced in Python, but new to kivy. I am trying to build a screen that has a `GridLayout` just south of center and sized at about `80%` by `80%`.

I have tried every tutorial I can find, but I haven't had any luck. This is what I'm trying:

```
class MyApp(App):
  def build(self):
    layout = FloatLayout()

    grid = GridLayout(cols=4, pos_hint={'center_x': 0, 'center_y': 0})
    layout.add_widget(grid)

    for queue in range(1,17):
      button = Button(text=str(queue), color=(0,1,0,1), font_size=40, 
                      size_hint=(0.1, 0.1))
      grid.add_widget(button)

    return layout

MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Could be more precise on what you already have tried, what didn't work and how? May be try providing a minimal running example, which shows your problem?

Comment: You will need to explain what you're actually seeing. Try to narrow in to what part of what you've tried doesn't seem to be working.